How do I get my system up update twilio plugin-flex to version 7
I currently have the @twilio-labs/plugin-flex version 6.4.2, but I want to upgrade to version 7.0.x.
When I run the command to upgrade it keeps re-installing 6.4.2
There does not appear to be any way to remove a plugin or force a version.  I cannot validate my plugin without version 7.0.x
My co-workers have newer machines and I think with a clean install they got version 7.0.2
System: Mac, M1, Node: 18.19.0

Have you tried changing the package.json reference to 7.0.x then running npm install?
If that doesn't work delete package-lock.json and try again.
This has worked for me in the past.

I had the same issue and it seems that the latest version available is 6.4.2. You can check this using "npm show @twilio-labs/plugin-flex". One of the options is to change the @twilio-labs/plugin-flex version to 6.4.2 in the package.json file as suggested on  https://github.com/twilio/flex-plugin-builder/issues/1034.
However, due to other dependencies' versions this might not work, in which case I found that creating a new plugin folder using the 6.4.2 version and merging the source files (from the previous plugin) in the new plugin folder fixes the issue.
